# Google Storage Transfer Service Unknown error: Details: Task stalled too long

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to directly transfer files from google drive to google storage bucket (so that I don't have to download and upload files manually). 
Source folder is public: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8YQPUJNvwckcnVyelNITWZHcE0

I have deployed an app that generates TSV file of above mentioned folder. It can be seen at: https://thanaponbuamongkol-project01.appspot.com/?folderId=0B8YQPUJNvwckcnVyelNITWZHcE0

Whenever I run transfer job using the URL mentioned above, I get

```
Unknown error: Details: Task stalled too long
```

[image: Unknown error: Details: Task stalled too long]

Note that

1. TSV file is valid (base64-md5 hash is correct, file size is also correct since I am using google drive api, URLs are also correct since I can download files manually using these urls), I have followed everything from https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-url-list
2. I am owner of project in which target bucket exits so this cannot be permission related issue.

Can anyone point me in the right direction because this error is not providing me any detail of what is wrong.

Comment: Did you found the root cause for the above issue? I am facing the same issue randomly (1 out of 10 times). Definitely it is not an code/permission issue, possibly issue with AWS side or GCS side. But root cause still mysterious for me, any findings from your side?

Comment: @JayaAnanthram Nope I didn't find any root cause

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, my file is 320GB and I'm able to download it.